# Can I find the class names on which a tensorflow pretrained model was trained on?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pre-trained-model

I am working with the following dataset:

https://www.kaggle.com/abdallahalidev/plantvillage-dataset

I have a pre-trained model for it. I have evaluated the model by following way:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model=load_model('plantvillage.h5')
model.evaluate_generator(test_image_gen)
model.metrics_names
```

But I couldn't figure out the the way on how to get the classes names from the pre-trained model. Is there any way or any statement to do this?

Comment: Class names are not saved since it's not part of the model. The model owner, should share information of class names associated with each output.

Comment: what about the number of classes? Can that be found or not??

Comment: @Junaid the number of classes should matcht the size of the last layer.

Comment: @Junaid In the case of 'Mask R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024' you can find the class names using   **PATH_TO_LABELS = './models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)** I suppose that this is true for all the TensorFlow Hub models

Comment: ImageNet, for example, provides a lookup table from coded output to human readable label. See here: *tf-imagenet/LOC_synset_mapping.txt at master · formigone/tf-imagenet · GitHub*